# MapReduce design

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Each line in the data comes in the following format:

UserId, Sex, Age

We need to answer the following 2 questions:

1)  How many Male & how many Females.

2)  How many over 50 years & how many under 50 years.

Is there a way to answer both these in a single Map Reduce job?  I know I can easily do this in 2 separate MR jobs, but would like to avoid reading the same file twice.  How can I do this in only one MR job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the map phase you can either for every record output 2 keys:

- young/old
- male/female

with count 1 as value and sum in the reduce phase which will give you the 4 values you are looking for, or alternatively output 1 key with combined information:

- youngmale/oldmale/youngfemale/oldfemale

with count 1 to be summed in the reduce phase giving you 4 combined values which you can use to get the answers you want by adding pairs of counts.

Answer (score 0):

suppose the output of your mapper to the reducer is like **`context.write(CONSTANT_KEY, VALUE);`** where key is a CONSTANT while VALUE is a concatenated string **`"X,Y"`**. `X` can hold 1 value either {1,0} where 1 stands for male & 0 stands female. `Y` can hold 1 value either {1,0} where 1 stands for age>50 & 0 stands age<50. Now in the Reducer class, you can easily count the number of 1s and 0s for field X & Y using **StringTokenizer** class. the only shortcoming is that, there will be only one reducer since the KEY is CONSTANT.

Comment: Sending all output with a constant key is not a good idea. You can't combine intermediate k,v pairs, meaning your bandwidth usage is much larger, and all keys go to the same Reducer, meaning you're overloading a single node instead of splitting the work between available nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question.  The following would work, right?

Mapper:

```
if (Male)
  emit("Male", 1)
else
  emit("Female", 1)

if (Age > 50)
  emit("Over 50", 1)
else
  emit("Under 50", 1)
```

Now these will go to 4 different reducers with 4 different keys: "Male", "Female", "Over 50" & "Under 50" and there's my answer, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the first option I described, it has as drawback to the second option that you have to emit 2 keys for every input record.

Comment: I would suggest using @rsp 's second option to save bandwidth. If you're going to be doing a large amount of processing on the data in the Reducer though, I'd suggest the first option. It's a problem of balancing bandwidth usage with processing time, pick whichever works best for you job.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks @rsp & HypnoticSheep